# Using roslibjs to read a ROS parameter

Tags: ros, rosbridge-suite, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have some Javascript code that uses rosbridge_suite (Hydro debian install under Ubuntu 12.04) and roslibjs (latest version) to read in a parameter value from the rosbridge server and then set its value in a form field.  It seems I don't understand the timing of when the parameter is read or the sequence in which Javascript functions are executed (or both) because I'm not getting the result I expected.

My code (included below) does the following:

- sets a default value for the parameter
- reads the parameter from the rosbridge server and, if not null, overrides the default value
- sets the value of a form field to the parameter value

What I see on my form is that I always get the default value, not the value from the parameter server.  If I put some log statements in my script, I see that the form value is getting updated before the parameter value is read via roslib even though the roslib code comes first.  I am also verifying that the value *is* being read from the parameter server correctly.

Here now is the relevant snippet:

```
var maxLinearSpeed = 0.2;

// Create a Param object for the max linear speed
var maxLinearSpeedParam = new ROSLIB.Param({
     ros : ros,
     name :  '/maxLinearSpeed'
    });

// Get the value of the max linear speed paramater
maxLinearSpeedParam.get(function(value) {
   if (value != null) {
       maxLinearSpeed = value;
       console.log(maxLinearSpeed);
   }
});

var formElement = document.getElementById('maxLinearSpeedDisplay');
formElement.innerHTML = maxLinearSpeed;
```

So if I set the value of the maxLinearSpeed parameter to 0.5 on the rosbridge server, then run my script, I always see the default value of 0.2 in the form field labeled 'maxLinearSpeedDisplay' instead of 0.5 as I expected.  Yet the statement console.log(value) above displays the correct value of 0.5.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137611/using-roslibjs-to-read-a-ros-parameter/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2014-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the roslibjs calls are asynchronous; they are event driven. When you call 'get', you are passing in a callback function that will be called whenever rosbridge responds to you request. This prevents blocking and waiting which will lock up the entire browser. You could move your `var formElement = document.getElementById('maxLinearSpeedDisplay'); formElement.innerHTML = maxLinearSpeed;` inside your callback function so that the HTML is updated whenever a response comes back.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2014-03-09**:
Ah ha!  Now I understand.  Many thanks--and yes, your suggestion does the trick.  Thanks!